# Save my link configuration with drush or else?

Tags: blocks, drush, navigation

I just modified my database so I can translate 2 link from a block that I made.

The translation won't show up until I go here `admin/structure/menu/item/1022/edit` and press Save.

I would like to know if it's possible to do this with Drush or something else. Im in a Multisite environnement with more than 100 site, I would like to automate that task.

I tried to make a custom module to try and save my configuration but it doesnt seems to work.
I followed these steps : http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-08-05/programmatically-creating-drupal-menu-link-item

Answer (score 0):

Block translation is difficult, as mentioned also in this interesting article about [Successful multilingual sites in Drupal7](http://www.appnovation.com/blog/successful-multilingual-sites-drupal-7).

Maybe you want to consider using the [BEAN](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module combined with the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module?

PS: [How make your Drupal website multilingual](https://www.acquia.com/blog/how-make-your-drupal-website-multilingual) is another related article.

Comment: The thing is that my database modification work !
I used the same command for 2 of my link and one work right after and the other one doesn't.